# How to add Query and Header parameter to REST request using groovy script in SoapUI?

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I'm new to Groovy scripting. I want to add Query parameter and header parameter as shown in below snap and want to select the Media-Type as "multipart/form-data" and also want to check the checkbox for "Post QueryString". How can I write groovy script to achieve above things?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfIZJ.png)

Comment: I belive, soapui allows to add headers and query parameters in easy and non programming way. Why do you need to do using groovy?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm doing E2E automation in groovy script where this is my requirement. I have single POST method in which I have to add or remove the parameters depending on test cases. So need code for this.

Comment: Even end to end automation can be done at least in this case without requiring to use groovy script.

Comment: Hi Rao, could you please suggest how to achieve this? I mean the only way I can see is adding or removing parameters through groovy script. Could you please help me achieving it the way you are suggesting?

Comment: Possible to see the sample project? and specify where do you have the obstacle?

Comment: May be you want to check https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Feature-Requests/Ability-to-parameterize-REST-API-Parameter-Names/idi-p/177123

Comment: Have you checked above link?